# PHPMailer y Gmail conect server error

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail

me veo en la penosa obligación de acudir a ustedes por ayuda. A pesar de que ya había posteado algo sobre PHPMailer resulta que ahora dejó de funcionar como de la nada. 
Les cuento: Tengo el siguiente código (omití la consulta mysql por parecerme innecesaria)

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

require ('conexion.php');

    $nombre = "";
    $link = "";

    $serial =    $_POST['serial'];
    $marca =     $_POST['marca'];
    $localidad = $_POST['localidad'];
    $barrio =    $_POST['barrio'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $mensaje =   $_POST['mensaje'];

///Consulta MySQL

    $correo_recibe = $valor['email'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Username = "bic***@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "*******";
$mail->setFrom('Bic****@gmail.com', 'Diana Hurtado');
$mail->addAddress($correo_recibe, 'Marcela Gomez');
$mail->Subject = '¡Alguien encontró tu bici!';
$mail->msgHTML("<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang='en'>
                <head>
                    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
                    <title>Título</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    Hola! ".$nombre.", desde BiciBogotá queremos informarte que al parecer alguien ha encontrado tu bici. Éstos fueron los datos que nos proporcionó: <br>

                    Datos de la bici

                    Serial: ".$serial."<br>
                    Marca: ".$marca."<br>

                    Dónde lo encontró?

                    Localidad: ".$nombre_localidad."<br>
                    Barrio: ".$nombre_barrio."<br>
                    Direccion: ".$direccion."<br><br>


                    Mensaje adicional: ".$mensaje."<br>

                    Si este mensaje ha sido de utilidad y has recuperado tu bicicleta reportalo <a href=".$link.">¡AQUÍ!</a><br> 
                        (o copia y pega este link: ".$link."),<br>
                         de esta manera ya no aparecerá más en la sección de bicicletas perdidas de tu perfil y no tendrás problemas con lo retenes de la ciudad.

                </body>
                </html>");

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error, el mensaje no ha sido enviado: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo."enviado";
}
```

Y el error que recibo:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c29sm4865365uaa.50 - gsmtp
2017-10-24 04:30:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2017-10-24 04:30:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [186.155.14.49]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2017-10-24 04:30:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-10-24 04:30:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-10-24 04:30:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-10-24 04:30:59
2017-10-24 04:30:59
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

He habilitado aplicaciones menos seguras en Gmail, también tengo correctamente la contraseña y el correo; además he habilitado y deshabilitado la línea extensión openssl.dll de php.ini en Xampp
He intentado un millón de cosas incluso descargando cURL (como salía en una página de error) La verdad sé que PHPMailer es el más recomendado para enviar correos y Gmail entre los mejores servidores sin embargo los errores un día se corrigen y al otro ya nada funciona.

Chicos realmente necesito de su ayuda, llevo bastante tiempo en las mismas. Ya no sé qué hacer

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, lee el https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting dice que pueden haber problemas con GoDaddy  y algunas otras cosas que pueden estar relacionadas a tu error.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Realmente he seguido al pie de la letra las instrucción del link, y no, nada funciona.

Comment: Prueba cambiando el protocolo de autenticación y el puerto $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Port = 465;

Comment: Prueba cambiando el host por smtp.gmail.com yo lo uso asi y me funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chicos muchas gracias por responder... Les cuento:
Realicé demasiadas modificaciones siguiendome de https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting y ninguna me servía.. Incluso los comandos `dig +short smtp.gmail.com` , `ping smtp.gmail.com` y  `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` daban respuestas exitosas. A mi forma de ver tiene que ver con GMail el cual ha implementado demasiadas restricciones para aplicaciones externas por lo que me cambié a Hotmail u Outlook.

Así:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';

$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Username = "****@hotmail.com";
$mail->Password = "****";
$mail->setFrom('****@hotmail.com', 'Nombre');
$mail->addAddress('****@gmail.com', 'Nombre');
```

Y el envío fue completamente exitoso
Pueda que no sea una solución completa (para quienes de verdad quieren usar GMail) pero al menos a mí me ha sacado de apuros.

De lo mejor esta página, espero haber sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en la propiedad host ya que indicas ssl:// y debería ser sin el protocolo ssl, ya que se indica en SMTPSecure:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

require ('conexion.php');

    $nombre = "";
    $link = "";

    $serial =    $_POST['serial'];
    $marca =     $_POST['marca'];
    $localidad = $_POST['localidad'];
    $barrio =    $_POST['barrio'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $mensaje =   $_POST['mensaje'];

///Consulta MySQL

    $correo_recibe = $valor['email'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Username = "bic***@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "*******";
$mail->setFrom('Bic****@gmail.com', 'Diana Hurtado');
$mail->addAddress($correo_recibe, 'Marcela Gomez');
$mail->Subject = '¡Alguien encontró tu bici!';
$mail->msgHTML("<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang='en'>
                <head>
                    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
                    <title>Título</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    Hola! ".$nombre.", desde BiciBogotá queremos informarte que al parecer alguien ha encontrado tu bici. Éstos fueron los datos que nos proporcionó: <br>

                    Datos de la bici

                    Serial: ".$serial."<br>
                    Marca: ".$marca."<br>

                    Dónde lo encontró?

                    Localidad: ".$localidad."<br>
                    Barrio: ".$barrio."<br>
                    Direccion: ".$direccion."<br><br>


                    Mensaje adicional: ".$mensaje."<br>

                    Si este mensaje ha sido de utilidad y has recuperado tu bicicleta reportalo <a href=".$link.">¡AQUÍ!</a><br> 
                        (o copia y pega este link: ".$link."),<br>
                         de esta manera ya no aparecerá más en la sección de bicicletas perdidas de tu perfil y no tendrás problemas con lo retenes de la ciudad.

                </body>
                </html>");

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error, el mensaje no ha sido enviado: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo."enviado";
}
```

Ademas he arreglado un par de errores, las variables que daban undefined (nombre_localidad y nombre_barrio, ya que sobra "nombre_".

Una vez ejecutes el código, probablemente te dará un error de seguridad y te llegará un email a la cuenta de gmail donde te explica como permitir las conexiones desde aplicaciones no seguras.

La única parte que quedaría por corregir sería "Nombre y link" que entiendo estarás con ello.

Saludos,

Comment: Hola, gracias. Revisaré el código y estoy respondiendo qué sucedió con eso :)

Comment: No me funcionó. Será que me va mejor si compro un host?

Answer (score 0):

Si tu codigo ya funcionaba. No lo has editado, no lo has migrado de servidor, no has cambiado de version de PHP, la contreseña de la cuanta es la misma.

El problema puede ser un error de DNS, un error de red, o un error en tu Firewall en el firewall.

Si el servidor de tu sitio es linux ó unix comprueba el acceso al servidor desde linea de comandos con:

```
nslookup smtp.gmail.com

nmap -p 587 -T4 -A -v smtp.gmail.com
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Es eso lo que ocurre, no he hecho nada en absoluto y simplemente deja de enviar. 
Ahora, cómo hago para determinar si es un error de DNS, de red o del firewall? Por cierto trabajo con windows 10.

Comment: Desactiva el firewall y el antivirus para probar. Si funciona crea las reglas necesarias. Y activa de nuevo el firewall y el antivirus.

Comment: Listo, ya los desactivé. Aún así no funciona....?

Comment: ya cambiaste **$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';** por **$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';** como te comento **jonilgz** ?

Comment: Sí señor, de hecho copié y pegué el mismo código :/
Será que si compro un host me irá mejor???

Answer (score 0):

a partir de PHP 5.6 se muestra este error en las nuevas versiones de PHP que tiene controles mas rigurosos para SSL. En PHPMailer Wiki encontré esta solución que me sirvió de mucho.

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
'verify_peer' => false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);
```